# Disabling asterisks in Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I recently switched to Linux Mint 19.1.

While typing passwords in terminal it shows asterisks. How can I edit my sudoers file to disable them (not deleting but disabling)?

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming/code questions. I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute the script below:

```
sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback.disabled
```

The above line will disable the functionality of the **0pwfeedback** package. Thus, the asterisks will be disappeared. Many solutions on the web are saying to delete it. Do not do that. In case you will need the asterisks back you will enable it again. This is how it must be done.

Comment: You say to rename that configuration,and I'd agree that deleting the configuration would be a hack. But I don't see why uninstalling the package would be a problem. You could always reinstall it if you need to. That was my question: why mess with the system configuration when you could just cleanly uninstall the package?

Comment: Deleting such security packages is really a huge problem. The asterisk is a part of the lib's functionality. Uninstalling the whole lib would be a really big security issue. Combined with custom user's preferences and configuration would make it much worst. In any case, I for one believe that off/on exist in order to use them properly and that's why I proposed this answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think that is important additional information that should be in your answer, not just in a comment!